# Red5 application setup on CentOS

Tags: centos, red5

I wrote a simple Red5 application on my Windows computer, and it works good.

I'm trying to run it on my VPS (CentOS). I have read the following tutorial and I changed what needs to be changed but I didn't succeed.

http://leonell24.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/how-to-create-new-red5-0-8-application-on-centos/

I want a easy way to setup Red5 application on CentOS, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

the installation of Red5 does not vary from windows. Red5 is provided as ZIP file.
You unpack it and then run red5.bat or red5.sh, depending on what kind of OS you are using.

For further details on what went wrong with your application you should basically study the log files and errors produced. There is no "magic trick" anybody can tell you :) 
You simply have to debug the problems like with any other software development => study the logfiles, eventually change the log level, include your own debug messages, test + run

Sebastian

Comment: Mr Sebastian, your answer is very helpful, I'm trying like you say, like reading log files, errors.. but i failed

Comment: you failed to read it :). What do you mean by "but I failed", have you found any exception or similar? Maybe you attach the log file somewhere so that people reading this thread can also read your log.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-Zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

As I am facing errors, I request you to contribute in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments  using new version netbeans, jdk for new version glassfish server(3.x).

Arumugam A.V

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on CentOS VPS:

**Install java (if not already installed)**

```
yum -y install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip' >> /etc/bashrc
```

**Install red5**

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0_1/red5-1.0.1.tar.gz
untar red5-1.0.1.tar.gz
mv red5-server-1.0 /usr/local
```

**Start red5**

```
cd /usr/local/red5-server-1.0
./red5.sh
```